# Why doesn't this Google Translate ad use the word "Translation" instead of "Translate"?

Tags: verbs, nouns

[image: Ad saying "Join the Translate Community"]

To my knowledge, "Translate" is a verb and not a noun. So why does the above advertisement by Google uses a verb? I mean why not "Translation Community"?

Comment: **translate** is what the app does. **Translation** is what the app produces as output.  They've decided to name the app after what it does not after what it produces.  And there they're using the name adjectivally.  Just as Microsoft could say "Join the Excel community".  **excel** is a verb too.

Comment: @TRomano As the names of products, “Translate” and “Excel” are proper nouns rather than verbs.

Comment: @NobodyNada: You've mistaken the point I was making.  They are verbs used as names. Just as Apple chose to call its app *Apple Pay* not *Apple Payments*.

Comment: If it were a regular English word (rather than a proper noun), then I'd say it should actually be *translator* rather than either *translate* or *translation*. But it's a name, so it's not a verb and it's not used syntactically as a verb.

Comment: Yet another problem that could be solved by not putting words in ALL CAPS. But of course, Google's UI design always has been, is, and will continue to be terrible.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

"Translate" here refers to the name of the product: Google *Translate*. This makes it a [noun-adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), I believe. You can see them use the full name elsewhere, when they have more room (emphasis added):

> #### [Help improve Google Translate](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534530?hl=en)
>
> You can help make our translations better, and even add new languages, as part of the ***Google Translate Community***.

Answer (score 3):

Although Laurel's answer has been accepted, I'd like to take a different angle.

The banner on Google's site reads:

> JOIN THE TRANSLATE COMMUNITY

Because the banner is on Google's own site it would stand to reason they're talking about their own product. Thus, you can drop the "Google" in Google translate as a way of [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)). You'd still be able to recognize the "Translate" as a product name because it's a [proper noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun), capitalizing the first letter. The confusion stems from the sentence being all uppercase.

If the sentence wasn't all capitals, the intent would be much clearer:

> Join the Translate community

Answer (score -1):

Its a product name so doesn't have to follow grammatical rules.
Like Donuts is a stylised spelling of doughnuts - thanks to Dunkin’ Donuts, even Facebook, which began as **The Facebook** Without "**the**" it seems **cleaner and simpler**. The same would be true with Google Translation without the "tion" seems cleaner, more snappy.

You can name a product anything you like; it can feature unusual uses, bozo collocations, unorthodox orthography, nonce words, nonsense words; it can even take something else's name, if it's in a different class of goods or services
In short there are no rules for products, just the creativity of branding to make an impact.